# Trying to use Eclipse (Mars) with Linked Folders for ESP8266 project

Tags: eclipse, esp8266, shared-directory

I have successfully built a number of projects with eclipse (mars) under windows 10 with copied common source and header files. I now want to refactor these projects to use the eclipse 'linked folder' facility.

[linked folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13DmT.png)

I have successfully created the common project and the linked source folders to it in the target project.

However when I try to compile the project the compiler can't see the linked folders...

[compiler error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlDLD.png)

I'd appreciate any help with this, or is it that the xtensa compiler under windows doesn't support linked folders??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO "linked folders" is a slightly borked feature as it raises expectations it can't fulfill. The folders are only linked within the Eclipse context. That means that as soon as you leave the safe Eclipse haven those links are gone.

What you actually want/need are links on OS level that also work on the command line i.e. you need them on the file system. Such symlinks are native on Unix(-like) systems but [there are ways to create them on Windows](https://superuser.com/q/1020821/46224) as well.

Comment: Thank you for that. I was guessing that that was the case but couldn't find anything in my searching. I created a 'junction' to the 'Common' project folder in the target project then, having removed the eclipsed 'linked folders', created a source folder and modified the makefile to suit and now it compiles!